# python requests does not work for https from apache with wsgi

Tags: python, django, python-requests

When I try a django view that loads an external URL using requests, I get a 'module' object has no attribute 'create_connection'. However, when I use urllib2 or the same requests code from the interactive shell, it works.

My environment:

- Python 2.5.2
- Requests 0.10.0 (I am using a 3rd party api which requires this version)
- Apache with WSGI inside a virtualenv for my django site
- Django 1.4.1
- Debian Linux 5
- I do not have SELinux (or any similar security)

I actually use 2 different APIs for completely different functions. They both require requests and they both give this error:

```
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value: 'module' object has no attribute 'create_connection'
Exception Location: /my/virtualenv/dir/lib/python2.5/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in connect, line 67
```

The mentioned line in the exception is:

```
sock = socket.create_connection((self.host, self.port), self.timeout)
```

It looks like the version of socket that comes with python 2.5 does not have the create_connection method (it was added in 2.6). However, I tried running the exact same code from the python interactive shell within the virtualenv and everything works. Also, requests 0.10.0 is supposed to work with python 2.5.

I created the following 2 test views because I suspected requests to be part of the problem:

```
def get_requests(request):
    import requests
    r = requests.get("https://google.ca")
    return HttpResponse(r.text)

def get_urllib(request):
    import urllib2
    r = urllib2.urlopen('https://google.ca')
    return HttpResponse(r.read())
```

The urllib view works, and the requests view gives me the same error as above.

The fact that urllib works indicates to me that Apache has permission to connect to the internet (its not a firewall issue).

I've done a tcpdump when trying the views, and requests never even attempts to connect out.

Any ideas? Please don't suggest using something other than requests because I am using 2 different 3rd party APIs which require it.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure the Python 2.5 you're running at the shell is the same executable, with the same stdlib and site-packages, as the one being run from Apache? In particular, if the virtualenv is standalone, make sure `socket.py` and `ssl.py` are the same files as in your system (or apache) stdlib, and `requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py` is the same file as in your system (or apache) site-packages.

Comment: Also, how did you get SSL in 2.5? Did you `pip-2.5 install ssl`, or otherwise install the PyPI backport package? Install a Debian python-ssl package? Did it come with some kind of custom Python 2.5?

Comment: I just checked and the shell and apache are running the same python and the same socket.py and requests file. I never installed python ssl.

Comment: If you never installed ssl, I don't understand how your sample code can be working—unless it's working by ignoring the https and requesting it as plain http?

Comment: I just installed ssl using: 'pip-2.5 install ssl' and now it has the same error from the interactive shell. It's odd because using tcpdump, I know that the interactive shell was using https. I don't understand why apache failed without ssl installed, but the shell only failed after I installed it.

Comment: It's possible that older versions of urllib3 and/or requests had workaround code to deal with the case where the `ssl` module isn't installed. From a quick look at [the 0.10.0 source](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/v0.10.0/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py) it seems pretty clear that the code to do HTTPS when `ssl` _is_ present can't possibly work on 2.5, because it unconditionally calls `socket.create_connection`, which seems like an obvious bug… but a bug nobody is going to fix, since 0.10.1 dropped 2.5 support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've run into a bug in requests 0.10.0 (or, really, in urllib3) with HTTPS in Python 2.5 with the `ssl` module installed.

If you trace through the [0.10.0 source](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/tree/v0.10.0/requests), you can see that if `ssl` is installed and you make an HTTPS requests, you are going to get to the `VerifiedHTTPSConnection.connect` method. This is also explained in comments in the [`HTTPSConnectionPool`](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/v0.10.0/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py#L397) source. But you don't really even need to trace through the source, because you already saw that from your tracebacks.

And if you look at [the source](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/v0.10.0/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py#L65) to that method, it unconditionally calls `socket.create_connection`, which is guaranteed to fail in 2.5.

The odds that anyone is ever going to fix this bug are pretty minimal. It looks like it was introduced in 0.10.0, and 0.10.1 resolved it by just dropping 2.5 support. (I'm not positive about that, because I can't find it in the bug tracker.)

So, what can you do about it?

First, note that, while `create_connection` is "higher level" than `connect`, there are only real advantage is that it does the name lookup before deciding what kind of socket to create. If you know you only ever care about IPv4, you can replace it with this:

```
self.sock = socket.socket()
self.sock.settimeout(self.timeout)
self.sock.connect((self.host, self.port))
```

If you care about IPv6, you can just borrow the [2.6 code](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.6/Lib/socket.py#l534) for `create_connection` instead.

So, you have a few options:

- Fork the source and patch `urllib3.connectionpool.VerifiedHTTPConnection.connect` to use the workaround instead of `create_connection`.
- Monkeypatch `urllib3.connectionpool.VerifiedHTTPConnection.connect` at runtime.
- Monkeypatch `socket` at runtime to add a `create_connection` implementation.

However, I wouldn't want to guarantee that 0.10.0 won't have further problems with Python 2.5, given the history.

Comment: Thanks. I figured I would have to make a change to requests (I just don't like doing that - but since I won't be updating requests, it won't be too much of an issue). My answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/17435816/263328) shows the change I made. I based it on your answer and https://github.com/p-push/pycurl/commit/ef9de858e0526ed1b7786be224472e17f01d8338

Answer (score 0):

From 0.10.1, requests dropped support for Python 2.5.

Upgrade your Python or use requests 0.10.0 version of requests.

> 0.10.1 (2012-01-23)
>
> PYTHON 3 SUPPORT! Dropped 2.5 Support. (Backwards Incompatible)

Comment: I am using 0.10.0 and I can't upgrade it due to a 3rd party requirement. And upgrading python is a much larger project that will require a lot of time and testing.

Answer (score 0):

Use requests 0.9.3. That works for sure with Python 2.5. We needed Python 2.5 support and either Kenneth told us to use that version, or that was the newest version we found that actually worked in practice. Just watch out for any API differences if you need to go back to using that version.

Comment: I've tried installing every version back to 0.8.9 and they all give the same error (and they all have the socket.create_connection method). Here is the source from version 0.8.2 https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/8693fc746f67d6e8a3dee80e7eb287d39da944bb/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py As you can see, its still there.

Comment: See https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/8693fc746f67d6e8a3dee80e7eb287d39da944bb/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py#L380 This suggests that is a real issue in urllib3 and you are only triggering it because you have the ssl module built and installed for that Python 2.5, which is causing certificate verification to be enabled. Were you specifically wanting to do certificate verification? If not, don't enable certificate verification by the requests module.

Answer (score 0):

As abarnert [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17432500/263328), this is caused by a bug in requests 0.10.0 and it won't be fixed since python 2.5 support was dropped in version 0.10.1.

So I edited this file requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py (on line 67).

The original line:

```
    sock = socket.create_connection((self.host, self.port), self.timeout)
```

I replaced it with:

```
    try:
        sock = socket.create_connection((self.host, self.port), self.timeout)
    except AttributeError:
        # python 2.5 fix
        sock = socket.socket()
        if self.timeout is not None:
            sock.settimeout(self.timeout)
        sock.connect((self.host, self.port))
```

With this change, everything is working.